# inserting uuid to dynamodb using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamo-local

I'm trying to insert UUID to dynamodb local but unable to find a way to do it. I'm using following command to insert an item (with @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey), but it is getting inserted as a string in the for "id" attribute. can someone provide me ways to get this uuid inserted?

Below command is on windows using AWS CLI:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name customer --item "{\"id\":{\"S\":\"@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey\"},\"firstName\":{\"S\":\"fname\"},\"lastName\":{\"S\":\"lname\"},\"createdDate\":{\"S\":\"01-Sep-2017\"}}" --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL --region us-west-2 --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1):

`@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` is Java SDK specific and is not supported by aws-cli. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html

Comment: Thanks, any other way of doing it through AWS CLI?

Comment: You need to create UUID before using put-item and pass it as a parameter.